# Configure Amazon EC2 User-Data with specific code for instance launch and restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am creating a AWS EC2 launch template that includes commands within the User Data field to perform actions when the instance is first launched (package updates, install software, format EBS volumes, etc). In addition to this I also want to perform tasks on reboot or subsequent starting of the instance, such as mounting existing EBS volumes and configuring and mounting volatile SSD volumes. I see that I can use MIME-type to have code run when instance restarts here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

So, I can clearly modify User Data **after** I initially launch the instance, but this is cumbersome as it likely needs manual intervention or requires waiting for the instance to have executed the initial User Data code that runs on initialization of the instance.

My question is:

Can the multi-part MIME format be configured to run code that will execute on initialization of the instance and other code that will run every time the instance restarts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that what you're trying to achieve is passing two sets of commands using Userdata. One set which will be executed on the instance creation and another set which should be executed every reboot. Please lemme know if I misunderstood it.

For the first part, you can use Userdata itself as you already know. For the commands that should run on every reboot, you can leverage `rc.local` .

The script `/etc/rc.local` is for use by the system administrator. It is traditionally executed after all the normal system services are started, at the end of the process of switching to a multiuser runlevel, etc. You might use it to start a custom service or for mounting additional Volumes.

To write into `/etc/rc.local` , you can download the command set from S3 and copy into the file or you can simply echo it. Example:

```
echo 'echo HelloWorld' >> /etc/rc.local
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! I simply needed to add `chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local` at the end.